# Find highest value in duplicated rows - R

Tags: r

I have a table of locality, city and number of listings. Some of the locality-city pairings are an error and there is junk data in there. There is a simple algorightm to identify the dummy rows:

- If the locality is a repeat; the real city is the one with the highest number of listings. Rest are dummy

I want a clean data frame with the dummy rows removed.

sample data below:

```
Locality <- c("Aloc", "Bloc", "Cloc", "Dloc", "Aloc", "ALoc", "Bloc", "Bloc", "Bloc", "Cloc",  "Dloc",  "Dloc")

City <- c("A","B","C","D","B","C","A","C","D","D","A","B")

Listings <- c(25,100,150,30,2,1,2,3,2,1,1,1)

l <- data.frame(Locality=Locality, City = City,Listings=Listings )
```

The outcome i want is:

[image]

Comment: You could use `library(dplyr)` and do: `l %>% group_by(City) %>% filter(Listings==max(Listings))` do get for each City, the row with the highest listing

Comment: Hi, I am not looking for locality with highest listings in every city. I am looking for "city where given locality has highest listings".  Only need to do this for duplicated localities. YOur algo would fail if there were a locality E for city A which was never duplicated. It should appear in the outcome as-is

Comment: in NicE's response, if you replace `group_by(City)` with `group_by(Locality)`, you should get the rows with the highest Listings for each Locality

Comment: Maybe there is a typo in your code. There is one `ALoc` while other ones are `Aloc`.  Please do fix it or explain better your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dups <- anyDuplicated(l$Locality)

while (dups != 0){
    target <- which(l$Locality == l$Locality[dups])
    if (l$Listings[target[1]] >= l$Listings[dups]){
        l <- l[-dups, ]
    } else {
        l <- l[-target, ]
    }
    dups <- anyDuplicated(l$Locality)
}
```

yields

```
> l
  Locality City Listings
1     Aloc    A       25
2     Bloc    B      100
3     Cloc    C      150
4     Dloc    D       30
6     ALoc    C        1
```